# select from union select with order by and group by in mongodb using aggregation

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I try to rewrite next SQL query to mongodb with using C# aggregation framework, but I can`t understand how to do it. I need union some results.

```
SELECT TOP 100 RES.Agent, RES.Type, RES.Opens FROM ((SELECT UA.ClientDomain AS Agent, UA.Type AS Type, COUNT(*) AS Opens 
                                                    FROM tReadConfirm AS RC INNER JOIN tUserAgent AS UA ON RC.UserAgentId = UA.Id
                                                    WHERE RC.UserId = 2654 AND RC.CampaignId = 27442  AND UA.Type = 1
                                                    GROUP BY UA.ClientDomain, UA.Type)
                                                UNION
                                                (SELECT UA.Family AS Agent, UA.Type AS Type, COUNT(*) AS Opens 
                                                    FROM tReadConfirm AS RC INNER JOIN tUserAgent AS UA ON RC.UserAgentId = UA.Id
                                                    WHERE RC.UserId = 2654 AND RC.CampaignId = 27442 AND UA.Type <> 1
                                                    GROUP BY UA.Family, UA.Type)) AS RES
                                                ORDER BY RES.Opens DESC
```

It`s my start code, but it does not do what I need

```
db.analytics.aggregate(
    {
        $match: { UserId: 4749, CampaignId: 93178}
    },
    {
        $group :
        {
            _id : 
            { 
                "Family" : "$userAgent.Family",
                "Type" : "$userAgent.Type",
                "ClientDomain" : "$userAgent.ClientDomain",
            }  ,
            "Opens": 
            {
                 $sum : 1 
            }
         }
     },
     {$sort :{"Opens":-1}}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer, it is my work code example. The operator "$cond" helps me.

```
db.analytics.aggregate(

    { 
        $match : { 
            "UserId" : 4790, 
            "CampaignId" : 93178} 
     },
     {
        $group :
        {
            _id : 
            { 
                "Type" : "$userAgent.Type",
                "ClientDomain" : { $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "$userAgent.Type", 1 ] }, then: "$userAgent.ClientDomain", else: "$userAgent.Family" }},
            }  ,
            "Opens": 
            {
                 $sum : 1 
            }
         }
     },
     {
         $sort :{"Opens":-1}
     },
     {
         $limit:10
     }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following idea:

1. Filter common part - you've done that in $match stage
2. Get new document structure by $project operator. Something like

   {Agents: 
   [{Agent: "$userAgent.Family", Index:0}, {Agent:"$userAgent.ClientDomain", Index: 1}], Type: "$userAgent.Type"}
3. $unwind the Agents fields, so you get 2 documents instead of 1 document with 2 element array.
4. Filter again with the following idea: {$or: [{Index: 0, Type:1}, {Index:1, Type<>1}]}
5. Group by Agent, Type and Index fields.

If I'm not mistaken, you will get the same results.

**EDIT:** Unfortunately step 2 will not work. [MongoDB: how create a new array field with the aggregate framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961368/mongodb-how-create-a-new-array-field-with-the-aggregate-framework)